# Resolving Issues calculating Mean in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of `Forest.Percent` for the data:

[image]

But I am getting error as:

> mean('Forest.Percent') NA
> Warning message:
> In mean.default("Forest.Percent") :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

The code I used is as shown:

[image]

Also, can we summarize the data in same fashion as mean?
How can these be solved?

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: `mean(RupandehiForest2014$Forest.Percent, na.rm = TRUE)`? `mean(your_df$Forest.Percent, na.rm = TRUE)`. Use e.g. `skimr::skim(your_df)` to get a nice summary of all variables.

Comment: Did you actually show us a picture of the code that generated the error message? The error message says: `mean('Forest.Percent')` and I do not see any code like that in your picture. If you did put the variable name in quotation marks, that is the problem. `Forest.Percent` is a character string, Forest.Percent is a variable name.